# error code [20001]; ORA-20001: ERROR-ORA-01722: invalid number ORA-06512

Tags: java, sql, oracle, date, time

i want to insert data to a table. Two of all column are date type. But i got that 
error code [20001]; ORA-20001: ERROR-ORA-01722: invalid number ORA-06512

this is my store procedure

```
PROCEDURE PR_SP_FAHMI (P_T_TABLE_UPLD_EXCEL IN PARAMS.EXCEL)
   is 
  P_LOGID VARCHAR2(255);
BEGIN
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO 
  PARAMS.EMPTY
  SELECT 
  C.PARA_OBJT_GROUP            ,
  C.PARA_OBJT_CODE             ,
  C.PARA_PROD_MATRIX_ID        ,
  C.PARA_PROD_CHANNEL_ID       ,
  C.PARA_PROD_SALES_GROUP_ID   ,
  C.PARA_CUST_GROUP            ,
  C.PARA_SLS_THROUGH_ID        ,
  C.ACTIVE                     ,
  C.LOGID                      ,
  TO_CHAR (C.CREATED_DATE,'dd/MM/yyyy HH24:MI:SS')  ,
  C.CREATED_BY                 ,
  TO_CHAR (C.MODIFIED_DATE,'dd/MM/yyyy HH24:MI:SS')              ,
  C.MODIFIED_BY                ,
  C.PARA_APPL_TAG
  FROM TABLE(P_T_TABLE_UPLD_EXCEL) C;
  EXCEPTION
        --  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
                NULL;
            WHEN OTHERS THEN
                RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'ERROR-' || SQLERRM);
        END;
END PR_SP_FAHMI;
```

this is my type :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE EXCEL AS TABLE OF PARAMS.T_OBJECT_FROM_EXCEL
```

this is my object :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE "T_OBJECT_FROM_EXCEL" FORCE AS OBJECT (
  para_objt_group            VARCHAR2(3),
  para_objt_code             VARCHAR2(3),
  para_prod_matrix_id        VARCHAR2(5),
  para_prod_channel_id       VARCHAR2(5),
  para_prod_sales_group_id   VARCHAR2(5),
  para_cust_group            VARCHAR2(3),
  para_sls_through_id        VARCHAR2(2),
  active                     NUMBER(1),
  logid                      NUMBER,
  created_date               VARCHAR2(255),
  created_by                 VARCHAR(20),
  modified_date              VARCHAR2(255),
  modified_by                VARCHAR(20),
  para_appl_tag              VARCHAR(8)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

`C.MODIFIED_DATE` and `C.CREATED_DATE` in your type is `varchar2` and to insert it into some `date` column, you need to convert it to date as follows:

```
TO_DATE (C.MODIFIED_DATE,'dd/MM/yyyy HH24:MI:SS')
-- same for C.CREATED_DATE
```

Make sure that the format of the date used in the above expression do match with the format of the string(`C.MODIFIED_DATE`) in your type.

Comment: after i follow your answer, i have error "error code [20001]; ORA-20001: ERROR-ORA-01843: not a valid month".

Comment: @Fahmi, please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: @Fahmi, additionally, if an answer solves your question, but raises another error, just edit your post, saying "I've done ..., which solved the first error, but now getting the following error:" so that other users can benefit from your progress. Additionally, it is generally a good strategy if facing errors, to reduce the number of columns. Just start with one column in the table and type. If that works add another one, etc.